# Is there efficient difference between varchar and int as PK

Tags: postgresql

Could somebody tell is it good idea use varchar as PK. I mean is it less efficient or equal to int/uuid?
In example: car VIN I want to use it as PK but I'm not sure as good it will be indexed or work as FK or maybe there is some pitfalls.

Comment: I guess there should be no pitfalls using a varchar column as a PK. Postgres is going to create automatically a Btree index which may be bigger than the one with an integer column, so with a potential worse performance to be confirmed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on which kind of data you are going to store.

In some cases (I would say in most cases) it is better to use integer-based primary keys:

- for instance, `bigint` needs only 8 bytes, `varchar` can require more space. For this reason, a varchar comparison is often more costly than a bigint comparison.
- while joining tables it would be more efficient to join them using integer-based values rather that strings
- an integer-based key as a unique key is more appropriate for table relations. For instance, if you are going to store this primary key in another tables as a separate column. Again, `varchar` will require more space in other table too (see p.1).

This [post on stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151253/non-integer-primary-key-considerations) compares non-integer types of primary keys on a particular example.